# Turn each character in an integer into an incrementing variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.4. This is my code:

```
number = int(1256)
```

I would like to turn each character in the integer into a variable, so like this:

```
number1 = "1"
number2 = "2"
number3 = "5"
number4 = "6"
```

I have tried using this line of code, but it doesn't work.

```
map(int, str(number))
```

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: Don't forget to vote, and accept the answer you found most useful!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
>>> list(str(number))
['1', '2', '5', '6']
```

Comment: nice and simple!

Comment: Not giving output as OP wants

Comment: @SandeepLade The output he provided is not text, is a simulation of the code he wants to do to achieve the same. I guess that is what he wants to do base on his try: `map(int, str(number))`

Comment: @SandeepLade But it's probably what the OP really needs. *Yours* on the other hand is neither what the OP asked for *nor* what they need.

Comment: @StefanPochmann and Francisco Rodríguez : But he wants number<index>:number , Where is it ? I changed my code to store it instead of printing

Comment: @SandeepLade It's nowhere. And *it shouldn't be*. That's a typical beginner mistake, thinking that something like that is the way to do something. Most certainly, it's not. Well, I mean it's nowhere in the form they asked for. It *is* there in the form of that list. For example `['1', '2', '5', '6'][2]` is `'5'`.

Answer (score 0):

use the modulo operator, and force integer division

```
number = int(1256)
n_arr = []
while number !=0:
    n_arr.append(str(number%10))
    number = (number)//10
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast into a string and unpack:

```
>>> number1, number2, number3, number4 = str(1256)
>>> number1
'1'
>>> number2
'2'
>>> number3
'5'
>>> number4
'6'
```